# Proving Cauchy inequality involving four expression

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, muirhead-inequality

Show that $$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) (a^2b^2 +b^2c^2 +c^2a^2) \geq (a^2b + b^2c + c^2a)(ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2)$$
i should prove this inequality by making it a Cauchy form inequality(as teacher stated).

my problem : this inequality is involving 4 parentheses but in other question i proved previously there was one or two in left side and one in right side.

things i have done so far:

$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) (a^2b^2 +b^2c^2 +c^2a^2) \geq (a^2b + b^2c + c^2a)^2$

Comment: As stated, the inequality you write is not true. For instance, it is false when you take $a = b = c = 1/3$. Perhaps there's a typo, or an extra hypothesis. Do you mean $(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)$ in place of $(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)$?

Comment: you are right .my teacher made a mistake.i changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have proved the inequality $$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)(a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2) \geq (a^2b + b^2c + c^2a)^2.$$ You are almost there! The square root of this equation tells us $$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^{1/2}(a^2b^2 + b^2a^2 + c^2a^2)^{1/2} \geq a^2b + b^2c + c^2a.$$

Now, you should be able to use identical arguments to prove that $$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^{1/2}(a^2b^2 + b^2a^2 + c^2a^2)^{1/2} \geq ab^2 + bc^c + ca^2.$$ Now what happens when you multiply the last two inequalities together?

Comment: when i multiply them it will became the question inequality. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set
$$P = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) (a^2b^2 +b^2c^2 +c^2a^2) - (a^2b + b^2c + c^2a)(ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2).$$
We have
$$P = \frac14\sum c^2\left[a^2+b^2+c^2+(a+b-c)^2\right](a-b)^2 \geqslant 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

It's $$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2-a^3b^3-a^4bc)\geq0,$$
which is just Muirhead:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2-2a^3b^3)+\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2-2a^4bc)\geq0,$$
which is true because $(4,2,0)\succ(3,3,0)$ and $(4,2,0)\succ(4,1,1)$.

Comment: It's a two year old Question with an Accepted Answer, so please try to give us a fuller explanation.

Comment: @hardmath I am ready to explain all step: 1. Expanding; 2. How we can use Muirhead... What do you wish to see exactly?

Comment: Thanks. It would be valuable to see [the verification that Muirhead's inequality applies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead's_inequality) by explicitly stating which sequence majorizes which other sequence of exponents.

Comment: @hardmath See my fixing.